# Properties.store() does not encode correctly and writes "?" instead of the respective mask

Tags: java, properties

When I want to write my properties with a certain charset, 90% of the masks work correctly and the corresponding special character is used.
For the masks, which cannot be encoded in the charset, a "?" is written instead of the mask/special character.
Is there a way to tell the store() method to only encode what it can and leave the masks that cannot be encoded?
This is what my store Method looks like:

```
 properties.store(new BufferedWriter(
        new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(destinationFile), StandardCharsets.ISO_8859_1)), "");
```

For example, in this case I just want to take the mask from the right side and not replace it with "?
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b3D3Z.png)

Comment: Character `\u2913` does not exist in the ISO 8859-1 character set.  Use a character set that supports the entire Unicode repertoire, like UTF-8.